# AWS S3 Upload on MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, amazon-s3

I've been trying to create a simple image upload to an Amazon S3 bucket feature in my MEAN stack app [following this method](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/Direct-S3-upload-and-Node-signing-example) but cannot get it to work.

(I'm using Heroku for hosting)

The error I receive in my console is the following: *net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT*

**Node:**

```
var s3 = {
    bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
    key: process.env.S3_KEY,
    secret: process.env.S3_SECRET,
    url: "https://<my-bucket-name>.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
}; 

app.post('/api/signing', function(req, res) {

    var request = req.body;
    var fileName = request.filename
    var path = '/avatar' + fileName;

var readType = 'private';

var expiration = moment().add(5, 'm').toDate(); //15 minutes

var s3Policy = {
    'expiration': expiration,
    'conditions': [{
            'bucket': s3.bucket
        },
        ['starts-with', '$key', path], 
        {
            'acl': readType
        },
        {
          'success_action_status': '201'
        },
        ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', request.type],
        ['content-length-range', 2048, 10485760], //min and max
    ]
};

var stringPolicy = JSON.stringify(s3Policy);
var base64Policy = new Buffer(stringPolicy, 'utf-8').toString('base64');

// sign policy
var signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', s3.secret)
    .update(new Buffer(base64Policy, 'utf-8')).digest('base64');

var credentials = {
    url: s3.url,
    fields: {
        key: path,
        AWSAccessKeyId: s3.key,
        acl: readType,
        policy: base64Policy,
        signature: signature,
        'Content-Type': request.type,
        success_action_status: 201
    }
};
res.send(credentials);
});
```

**Angular View:**

```
myApp.controller('profileController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$route', '$window', '$routeParams', 'Upload', function($scope, $http, $location, $route, $window, $routeParams, Upload){

$scope.onFileSelect = function(files) {

        if (files.length > 0) {
            var filename = files[0].name;
            var type = files[0].type;
            var query = {
                filename: filename,
                type: type
            };

            $http.post('/api/signing', query)
                .success(function(result) {
                    Upload.upload({
                        url: result.url, //s3Url
                        transformRequest: function(data, headersGetter) {
                            var headers = headersGetter();
                            delete headers.Authorization;
                            return data;
                        },
                        fields: result.fields, //credentials
                        method: 'POST',
                        file: files[0]
                    }).progress(function(evt) {
                        console.log('progress: ' + parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        // file is uploaded successfully
                        console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'is uploaded successfully. Response: ' + data);
                    }).error(function(err) {
                        console.log(err)
                    });
                })
                .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.

                    console.log(data, status, headers, config)
                });
    }
};

}]);
```

**View (HTML):**

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ngf-change="onFileSelect($files)">
```

**CORS Policy**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:5000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://www.ps101.com/</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
 </CORSRule>
 </CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the fix was extremely simple. Since I'm in the east coast of the USA, changing the URL simply to:  url: "https://.s3.amazonaws.com" fixed the problem. I believe this is the default for us-east-1 region out of N. Virginia.